# Identifying outlier loci in R

Tags: r

I have done some genome scan analysis and I want to identify the outlier loci. For an expected value of the FRD equal to q = 10, a list of candidate loci can be obtained by using the Benjamin-Hochberg procedure as follows:

```
q=0.1
L = length(adjusted.p.values)
W = which(sort(adjusted.p.values) < q * (1:L) / L)
candidates = order (adjusted.p.values)[w]
```

and this is part of the outliers and my output

```
head(candidates)
 [1]  3  4  9   10  13
```

But I need the output in a different type.
I want to assign TRUE if a locus has been chosen as outlier and FALSE if it has not

```
  head (desired_output)

  [1] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Any idea how can I modify the Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Devon said, removing the `which` will give you `W` as a logical vector that can be used to index the *sorted* p-values. To get a logical vector that can be used to subset the original (unsorted) values you’ll need to go a step further:

```
candidates = is.element(1 : L, order(adjusted.p.values)[W])
```

However, I’m not sure this will work with your data: the name `adjusted.p.values` suggests that these values are *already* FDR-adjusted. So you cannot/should not perform additional correction on them. If they are already adjusted, then you can get candidate loci simply by

```
candidates = adjusted.p.values < q
```

Comment: Thanks@Konrad Rudolph.candidates = is.element(1 : L, order(adjusted.p.values)[W]) did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `which()`, which is converting the boolean vector to a vector if indices to `TRUE`.